# Get data of the woocommerce from zoho creator

Tags: woocommerce

I have orders placed in the woocommerce . I need to get the order details from woocommerce by  using Zoho creator invoke URL function. woocommerce provides the consumer key and secret. I question where and how to put the key and secret in the invoke url function.?

Below is thewoocommerce API to get the order details.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders
```

I used postman to get the order details. I put the consumer key and secret as a username and password in the Postman.
got the data. it is working. but I don't know how to use the consumer key and consumer secret in the zoho creator invoke URL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give you an idea on how it works. When you use basic auth in Postman, it will internally add a [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header to your request. You can see the same by opening the console at bottom left.

**Reference:** [Authorization Header Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#examples)

**On Creator Deluge:**

```js
username = "consumer key here";
password = "consumer secret here";
authtoken = zoho.encryption.base64Encode(username.concat(":").concat(password));


header_data = Map();
header_data.put("Authorization", concat("Basic ", authtoken));

response = invokeUrl
 [
   url: "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"
   type: GET
   headers: header_data
 ];
```